# How can i make my own chips component in angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms

My goal is to make the following example

```
https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples
```

i want to build custom input chips component.

Until now i have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="search">
                <i class='fa fa-search icon-pos color-purple'></i>
            </label>
            <form [formGroup]='stateForm' autocomplete="new-password" novalidate autocomplete="off">
                <input id='search' placeholder="Search for a state" formControlName='search' (click)=' openDropDown() '
                    class='input-underline search-bar' type='text'>
            </form>
            <div documentClick (documentClick)="closeDropDown($event)" targetElementId="search">
                <div *ngIf='showDropDown' class='search-drop-down '>
                    <div (click)='selectValue(s)' class='search-results '
                        *ngFor="let s of states | searchFilter: getSearchValue() : propertyValueToShow ">
                        <a [innerHTML]="s[propertyValueToShow] | letterBold: getSearchValue()">
                            {{s.name}}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*TS*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: './autocomplete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./autocomplete.component.scss']
})
export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit {

  stateForm: FormGroup;
  showDropDown: boolean = false;
  propertyValueToShow: string = 'name';
  selectedOption: any;
  states = [{ name: 'Texas', age: '33' }, { name: 'Michigan', age: '32' }, { name: 'Washington', age: '20' }]

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.initForm()
  }

  initForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.stateForm = this.fb.group({
      search: [null]
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  selectValue(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.stateForm.patchValue({ "search": value[this.propertyValueToShow] });
    this.selectedOption = this.stateForm.controls.search.value[this.propertyValueToShow]
    this.showDropDown = false;
  }

  closeDropDown(ev) {
    if (ev == "open") {
      this.showDropDown = true;
    } else {
      this.showDropDown = false;
    }
  }

  openDropDown() {
    this.showDropDown = false;
  }

  getSearchValue() {
    return this.stateForm.value.search;
  }

}
```

so currenlty when i click on some option i get value on my input from the selected option.
I make that with

```
selectValue(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.stateForm.patchValue({ "search": value[this.propertyValueToShow] });
    this.selectedOption = this.stateForm.controls.search.value[this.propertyValueToShow]
    this.showDropDown = false;
  }
```

but i can't find a way to save multiply options on my input

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be like

```
this.stateForm.controls.search.setValue([[...arr].join(' ')]);
```